# Filter users in a search

Tags: users

I have made a custom search in users in wordpress and I added it to the landing page by using a shortcode. I want to filter them according their roles, it means I want to exclude all Admin users.
How can I do that?
This is my code:

```
    if (isset($_POST['member'])) {

        foreach (get_users() as $user) {
            $name_lower = strtolower($user->display_name);
            $name = $user->display_name;
            if (strpos($name_lower, strtolower($_POST['member'])) == false) {
                $resultat = $name;
            }
        }
    }
    return $resultat;
}
add_shortcode('resultat', 'recherche_resultat');
```

Answer (score 1):

Check the arguments for `get_users()`

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_users/

What you should do is

`$users = get_users( array( 'role__not_in' => array( 'administrator' ) ) )`

Then

`foreach ( $users as $user ) ...`